# How can I make a recyclerview that jumps to the next 3 items?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am working on an app that has a look& feel similar to the Android Netflix app.

When I open the netflix app, I see the three movies (in "My list") in the middle of my screen:
https://www.androidcentral.com/sites/androidcentral.com/files/postimages/444537/profiles-netflix-2.png

This view has interesting properties when showing movie 1,2 and 3:

1. When I scroll to the next movie (number 4) in the list I see this is possible.
2. But when I release my finger, it jumps back and I see the first three movies.
3. If scroll to movie 5 and release my finger it jumps further and I see movie number 4,5 and 6.

This behaviour is not entirely default. For instance, when I scroll in twitter to the next tweet, it does not jump back or so.

So how do I enable this netflix like behaviour in a recyclerview? It may be relevant to say that I use the support library:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html

It may also be relevant that I use Xamarin. However, If you show java code that demonstrates how to fix it, it will most likely help me as well.

Comment: Read more about [LayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.LayoutManager.html). These kind of things you wish are done with it

Comment: use recyclerview scrolling behaviour and detect your last item position and according to that scroll to desire position

Comment: or maybe use GestureDetectorListener, Read here - https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html